# Interpretation of * in command line arguments C++

Tags: c++

Hi have a c++ program that elaborates a set of files with the same prefix (i.e file0, file1, file2, etc.). When I run the program (on linux systems) I usually pass the prefix as command line argument:

```
myscript file*
```

this elaborates all the files (within the folder) that have prefix file. The c++ script includes a for loop as:

```
for(i=1;i<argc;i++) {
//do something
}
```

I'm not an expert of c++ and I don't know how * is elaborated. Now, how could I pass a subset of files (i.e from file0 to file10 or from file20 to file35) to the c++ program? How can I use the shell commands to list a subset of files?

Comment: On Posix systems, the file globbing (hence expansion of `file*` into a sequence like `fileA`, `fileCC` ...) is done by the shell. And what is a `cpp` *script*?

Comment: have you tried it out?

Comment: Why is this on hold as “unclear”? Despite some minor grammatical errors, it is clear to me and at least three people answered it before it was put on hold.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are running on a linux-like system, the * is evaluated by the shell, before executing your program (which by the way is called a program, not a script, as it first has to be compiled before execution).

So the shell expands the * to match everything.  This means you should modify how call the program, rather than modifying the code.  For example File0* would match anything beginning with a File0.

Chances are good you are working with a bash terminal, in which case you should be looking for command line help.  The GNU project publishes a great book called "introduction to the command line" (http://shop.fsf.org/product/Introduction_to_Command_Line/)  which is released under the gpl and freely available.  You might enjoy it.

You might like to be aware that your line:  for(i=2; i
First, you are setting i to two, which skips over the first command line parameter.  argv is an array where the 0'th element is the command itself, and all options are in elements 1 to argc-1.   If you are intentonally skipping the first argument, then that's fine.

The second is a pretty small one, but it's a good idea to get in the habit of preferring the prefix increment operation (++i) over the postfix.  It won't make a difference on a simple integer, but in some cases using the prefix operator results in more efficient code (by avoiding an unnecessary temporary).  Since the prefix operator is just as readable as the postfix, you lose nothing by getting the habit of always using the prefix operator, unless you really need the postfix one.  This is discussed quite well in, for example, Item 1 (don't optimize or pessimize prematurely) of Sutter and Alexandrescu's C++ Coding Guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Basile is right, the cpp program sees only real file names. The sequence of file names passed to the program is the result of the shell's file name expansion: In a directory with files a1, a1, a3, a11 a command like `echo a[0-9]`would result in "a1 a2 a3".

The bash does not have true regular expressions, so you would need to pipe the ls command through grep in order to get all files named f1...f100 or so (with different number lengths). Example: `ls | egrep 'file[0-9]+'`.

A program "my_executable" would get the result on the command line with something like

```
my_executable $(ls a* | egrep 'a[0-9]+$')
```

Putting a command inside $() replaces $() with the output of that command.
Hope that helps.